# Is there an international standard for region codes that defines the European Union?

Tags: data, geocoding

I have seen the [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) defines 2-letter, 3-letter and numerical codes for countries around the world. However, the European Union does not seem to have a code.

Is there an international standard for region codes that defines the European Union and maybe other political/economic unions/regions?

Comment: The European Union isn't a country.  NATO isn't one either. Nor OPEC. None of these treaty organizations has a country code, and that doesn't seem wrong. Discussion of this doesn't seem GIS-centric.  Maybe in [politics.se]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UN maintains M49 codes for every country, continent and some regions. There is not one for countries in the EU, but there are several others for various political/economic regions. I'm not sure how many non-UN datasets use these codes but they do exist. I'm dropping the UN's M49 methodology page below, as well as the wikipedia page on M49 (it has all of the codes and what they correspond to listed).

https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M49

UPDATE:
This github maintains a nice csv file of country codes (including the m49 codes, and several others like ISO 3166) which you can join with your data set if it is helpful to you
https://github.com/datasets/country-codes/blob/master/data/country-codes.csv